# JPA Enty Manager Cache Query

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I have a strange behavior with the EntityManager and searches.

1. First, I run a query against the entity manger:

`Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(jpql);`

2. Second, I get the results.

   `List<DBEntityObject> results = q.getResultList();

   for(DBEntityObject  x: results) {
           x ==> SHOWS OLD VALUES!!!
   }`

The returned objects are not updated !!!! But the Query [point 1] is made against updated data, **Otherwise should not return any results**

The fact is tha query will be held against updated values, but they are getting cached !!

I am including this on persistence unit:

```
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.size.default" value="0"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.type.default" value="None"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.refresh" value="true"/>

        <property name="eclipselink.query-results-cache" value="false"/>
```

Comment: So given that you complain about "old values", there must also be a component to this story you are entirely ignoring: there is also mutating of data going on. So how is that happening?

Comment: Some details such as an example query, data and the changes made might help as well. Where and when was the EntityManager obtained and are you aware that each EntityManager has its own cache?